# How do I $setValidity on an angular element in a form in $modal from within a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have an angular-ui $modal which users use to rapidly create a new element. When they do, I want to check that an element is unique. It calls `$save(item)` in the controller, which tries the save. If it succeeds, it closes the `$modal`, if not and returns a 409, it should set a validity error.

My modal template looks like:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form name="createItem">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input ng-model="item.name" name="name"></input></td><tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$save(item)">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The controller that launches the modal looks like this:

```
  $scope.createItem = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       templateUrl: '/partials/createItem.html',
       controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.item = {};
          $scope.$save = function(item) {
            var s = new Item(item).$save({},function () {
                modalInstance.close();
            },function (httpResponse) {
                if (httpResponse.status === 409) {
                    // I WANT TO SET VALIDITY HERE
                } else if (httpResponse.status === 400) {
                    // I WANT TO SET VALIDITY HERE
                } else {
                    // I WANT TO SET VALIDITY HERE                                  
                }
            });
         };
       }
     });
};
```

How do I $setValidity on the particular element?

UPDATE:

It appears that the $scope inside the controller has 2 child scopes. The second has all of the usual `$scope.createItem` form elements, etc.

Comment: Inside your controller try:

$scope.createItem.name.$setValidity('server-error', false);

Comment: I tried. `$scope.createItem` is blank. I steppe through it in firebug and found that one of the child scopes has `$scope.createItem`, but that doesn't really help...

Comment: That's because as per the docs `$modal` creates a child scope for the modal contents. Best to work around this is to pass the form to your save function: `ng-click="$save(item, createItem)"` and then you have access to the form in your function, so calling `createItem.name.$setValidity('server-error', false);` should then work as expected.

Comment: @Beyers that is very smart! Please write it as an answer.

Comment: Is there a better, more "official" (or Angular-ish) way to do this? Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: BTW, does `resolve` as part of angular-ui help with this? Isn't that just one-way (parent to child)?

Comment: Some would argue you need to create a directive for that, that listens to events from your controller and then set the validity through the directive. Personally I think what you are doing is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: `resolve` will not help you in this case, it is meant to resolve items you want to pass to the controller as locals, and you wont have access to the child scope there, or at least I dont think you will.

Comment: @Beyers, how would you do this with a directive? I am not rendering anything here, but trying to do a save (which is a controller activity), and get the results. If this were a regular form, it would all be right there in the controller, and I would set validity. Can you explain how to do this with a directive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61627/discussion-between-beyers-and-deitch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), `$modal` creates a child scope for the modal contents. Best to work around this is to pass the form to your save function: `ng-click="$save(item, createItem)"` and then you have access to the form in your function, so calling `createItem.name.$setValidity('server-error', false);` should then work as expected.

Comment: turns out that my problem was other directives, so I had scopes inside of scopes. I find it hard to believe I am the only one to have this issue. I will open a new question on embedded scopes.